# Java Enum Value represent java.lang class

Tags: java, class, enums, instanceof

I am trying to create a program that creates it's own little database type thing(Just cause I want some extra stuff to do for it) and I have run into a small mishap. When I try and set the value for the value of the table, I obviously must check to see if it is the right type. In my `Value` class, I have the `setValue` function:

```
public void setValue(Object value){
    ValueType t = getColumn().getType();
    if(value instanceof t){
        // Is the correct type.
    }
    this.value = value;
}
```

Where `ValueType` is the Enum of the types of available values. Here is the class:

```
public enum ValueType {

    STRING, INTEGER, BOOLEAN, FLOAT

}
```

So that works until the line:

```
if(value instanceof t){
```

IntellIJ Idea is saying that `t` is an unknown class. So I am trying to make it so that `t` will represent a `String` or `Integer`. Thank you for your time, and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add the following method to your enum:

```
public enum ValueType {
    STRING, INTEGER, BOOLEAN, FLOAT;

    public boolean isInstance(Object obj) {
        // Generate a class name from enum name
        String className = "java.lang."+name().substring(0, 1)+
                               name().substring(1).toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            // Try to resolve this class and check the supplied object type
            return Class.forName(className).isInstance(obj);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can write `if(t.isInstance(value))`.

However I would recommend to store the `Class` object in the enum, like this:

```
public enum ValueType {
    STRING(String.class), INTEGER(Integer.class), BOOLEAN(Boolean.class), FLOAT(Float.class);

    private Class<?> clazz;

    ValueType(Class<?> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public boolean isInstance(Object obj) {
        return clazz.isInstance(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would add considering a generic if possible. Then you don't even need the enum.